# Ondelete cascade odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I need to delete partner who have login in `res.users` table. when i try to delete that partner i getting an error:

`except_orm: ('Integrity Error', 'The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:\n- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it\n- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set\n\n[object with reference: Res users - res.users]')`.

So i have changed attribute value of `ondelete` from `restrict` to `cascade`of field `partner_id` in `res.users` table. Similarly in `change_password`. Now its works fine. But is there will be any problem occur due to this change in odoo behavior, like invoice?.

Comment: If there is any invoice in the name of the customer then the customer can't be deleted

Comment: Is there any way to delete/remove partner without throwing IntegrityError:?.

Comment: First delete all the related invoice by accessing database and then you can delete the customer.

Comment: Download pgadmin 4 for accessing database in GUI format

Comment: If i delete invoice that will affect the accounting reports like balance sheet and profit & loss.

Comment: What about the field 'active'? what is the functionality of it?

Comment: oh I didn't think about that sorry I don't know the answer then

Comment: active is a field to give the impression that the record is deleted. odoo have a default filter when you use search is always return the record with active=True. so by default if a record is active=False is not shown by odoo only if you tell it too show it using some domain.